# Any way to create a NumPy matrix with C API?

Tags: python, numpy, python-c-api

I read the documentation on NumPy C API I could find, but still wasn't able to find out whether there is a possibility to construct a matrix object with C API — not a two-dimensional array. The function is intended for work with math matrices, and I don't want strange results if the user calls matrix multiplication forgetting to convert this value from an array to a matrix (multiplication and exponentiation being the only difference that matrix subclass has).

Comment: What do you mean by "matrix"? Is it `numpy.matrix` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numpy.matrix` is an ordinary class defined in [numpy/core/defmatrix.py](http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/numpy/browser/trunk/numpy/core/defmatrix.py#L154). You can construct it using C API as any other instance of user-defined class in Python.

Answer (score 6):

You can call any python callable with the `PyObject_Call*` functions.

```
PyObject *numpy = PyImport_ImportModule("numpy");
PyObject *numpy_matrix = PyObject_GetAttrString(numpy, "matrix");
PyObject *my_matrix = PyObject_CallFunction(numpy_matrix, "(s)", "0 0; 0 0");
```

This will create a matrix `my_matrix` of size 2x2.

*EDIT:* Changed references to `numpy.zeros`/`numpy.ndarray` to `numpy.matrix` instead.

I also found a good tutorial on the subject: [http://starship.python.net/crew/hinsen/NumPyExtensions.html](http://tinyurl.com/NumPyExtensions)

Comment: OP asks `numpy.matrix` but `zeros` returns `ndarray`.